# How to extract a number from response body in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am calling 2 different endpoints in my jmeter test. 
The first endpoint should provide me with a single number (for instance 568959) in its response body and then I must pass it to my second endpoint.

Here is the response of my first endpoint:

[image]

please notice the response contains a single number, and it is not a `json` response as you see in image.

and then I used a `Regular Expression Extractor` to extract this number from the body using a variable called `newsId` and regular expression as `(.*)` as below:

[image]

But, when I run my second request, I noticed it is sending an empty `${newsId}` such as:

```
https://www.example.com/blabla/rest/news//publish
```

Comment: Can you share the publish news thread group, so we can spot some problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about how you are passing the Regex values to the second end point. But try this below method. It may work.

After the Regex, add a Bean shell assertion and pass the variable newsId as

```
${__setProperty(newsId,${newsId})}
```

**Explanation :** 
${newsId} -> Pass the regex variable here in the setProperty.

Now try passing the variable in the second end point. For reference please follow the below link.

https://medium.com/@priyank.it/jmeter-passing-variables-between-threads-a4dc09903b59

Answer (score 0):

You either need to amend your request and change `${newsId}` to `${newsId_g0}` or `${newsId_g1}` as your setup generates the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

[image]

You can visualize defined JMeter Variables or Properties using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) combination, check out [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) article for more details.

Alternatively you can amend `Template` section of your [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and set its value to `$1$`

[image]

this way you will not need to change `${newsId}` declaration